# Adding edge properties using DseGraphFrame API

Tags: datastax-enterprise

If I want to add edges with properties as data frames, what format should the properties data be in? I'm reading these [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/dseGraphFrameMapping.html?hl=dsegraphframe), but it doesn't address anything about the format of the properties columns.

For instance:

```
Dataset<Row> edgesToAdd = sparkDataSetContainingData
            .select(
                dseGraphFrame.idColumn(lit(srcLabel), col("sourceName")).as("src"),
                dseGraphFrame.idColumn(lit(destLabel), col("destinationName")).as("dst"),
                lit(inputEdgeLabel).as("~label"),
                dseGraphFrame.idColumn("some_property_key", col("some_property_value")) // is this correct?
            );

    dseGraphFrame.updateEdges(edgesToAdd, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be correct - you must have 3 columns: `src`, `dst` & `~label`.  First two are generated using the `idColumn` function that accepts vertex label and vertex ID as parameters.  You can see that in the [following example](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/dsegraphframes-spark-filtering/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/spark/graphframes/App.scala#L129) from `DataStax-Examples`.

There is also a lot of resources available on that topic:

- [blog post introducing DSE GraphFrames](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2017/05/introducing-dse-graph-frames)
- [blog post about best practices working with DSE GraphFrames](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/11/datastax-enterprise-graphframes-best-practices)
- [presentation from Graph Day 2018](https://www.slideshare.net/JimHatcher/graphframes-access-methods-in-dse-graph)
- [DS332 course](https://academy.datastax.com/#/online-courses/1b5076c3-b728-488f-a841-b8ec3e285a39) on DSE Graph Analytics